# Data Transfer in Fragments/Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi i am new to **Fragments** i searched many pages but still i didn't get correct answer for my questions. I want to know how **data transfer while implementing Fragments**. I have three cases

*1. Fragment to Fragment data transfer* : By implementing a **Callback Interface**

*2. Fragment to Activity data transfer* : By using **getActivity()**.

*3. Activity to Fragment data transfer* :  My problem was occurred here. I referred many sites but nobody given clear explanation.Please help me.

Comment: You want know how to transfer data from the activity to the fragment at the time of creation of the fragment or at run time, after the fragment is created?

Comment: @LucasSantos : i need in both situvations

Answer (score 0):

For transfer data at the time of creation of the fragment, do this:

```
Fragment newFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(any argument);
```

In constructor of fragment, do this:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int someInt) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", someInt);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

Then for instantiate a fragment now, you make call `newInstance()` instead of new `Fragment()`. For recover the data of a fragment on fragment, do this:

```
int myData = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
```

For transfer data from activity to fragment in a time of execution implementing a Callback Interface too.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to have a reference in your activity to the fragment,
then make your fragment register in your activity using an interface:

```
public interface RegisterFragment {
    public void setFragmentReference(MyFragment frag);
}
```

implement the interface in your activity, which defines a method to save a fragment reference:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements RegisterFragment {

    private MyFragment myFragmentReference;


    public void setFragmentReference(MyFragment frag) {
        this.myFragmentReference = frag;
    }


    public void usingFragmentReference() {
        if(myFragmentReference != null)
            myFragmentReference.doSomething("string data");
    }

}
```

In your fragment subclass, save the reference using the interface method:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        RegisterFragment rf = (RegisterFragment)getActivity();
        rf.setFragmentReference(this);
    }

    public void doSomething(String data) {
                ...
    }

}
```

This way your activity can communicate with your fragment when required.